# Email markup for EventReservation not working

Tags: google-calendar-api, schema.org, google-schemas

I'm trying to use the Gmail Email Markup to create an automatic event in Google Calendar. From the official guide, I'm using the below code:

```
<html>
  <body>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":              "http://schema.org",
  "@type":                 "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber":     "IO12345",
  "underName": {
    "@type":               "Person",
    "name":                "John Smith"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type":               "Event",
    "name":                "Google I/O 2013",
    "startDate":           "2017-11-16T08:30:00-08:00",
    "location": {
      "@type":             "Place",
      "name":              "Moscone Center",
      "address": {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":   "800 Howard St.",
        "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
        "addressRegion":   "CA",
        "postalCode":      "94103",
        "addressCountry":  "US"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<p>
  Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
</p>
<p>
  BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
  Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
  Order for: John Smith<br/>
  Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
  Start time: Nov 16th 2017 8:00am PST<br/>
  Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
</p>
```

But this is not working. It isn't creating an event. Any idea why? Also, I have add automatic events from Gmail enabled in my Calendar settings. I'm getting other automatic events of flight bookings on my calendar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you test it by sending an email from and to the same address? IIRC, there was a case where the schemas don’t work in that case.

Comment: No, I'm sending it from a kind of a no-reply email address from my web application to my personal email address.

Comment: I miss the "reservationStatus" in your code.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#basic_event_reminder_without_a_ticket

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an educational account (school / university). Try it with a regular gmail account.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum, it is question and answer. Please avoid posting "me too" as answers.